# Installing pigpio into a virtual environment

Tags: python, installation, virtual, environment

I wanted to ask on how I can install a library appropriately in a virtual environment. I am currently having difficulties using a Servo library called pigpio upon installation when I activate a virtual environment on my Raspberry Pi Zero W.

The problem arise if I leave out ‘sudo’ in my bash commands in terminal (i.e.python myscript.py) since using the command ‘sudo python myscript.py’ would render another module of this script (Boto3) unavailable in the virtual environment.

The error message when I used the sudo command goes:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "myscript.py", line 13, in 
import pigpio
ImportError: No module named Boto3

On the other hand, using a non-sudo bash command results in pigpio, the Servo library module being unavailable.

I suspect the problem lies in the process of installation of pigpio library as I had to use ‘sudo make install’ in one of the steps. I think I might need to install via an alternative method that avoids global installation i.e. sudo. My understanding is that only pip can install packages into a virtualenv (from Pypi) (v.s. sudo which leads to global installation). Is there a way that I can find another way to appropriately install a library into a virtual environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to uninstall all dependencies from the system wide modules:

```
sudo pip uninstall boto3 pigpio
```

`cd` to a directory like /home/your_user and then retry installing the dependencies in the venv like:

```
virtualenv venv_test
source venv_test/bin/activate
pip install boto3
cd pigpio
```

Maybe a hacky edit to https://github.com/joan2937/pigpio/blob/master/Makefile#L34 to be inside your venv folder? like `$(pwd)/venv_test`:

```
make
make install
deactivate
source venv_test/bin/activate
```

It can get complicated with permissions and module paths if using `--system-site-packages` or something similar.

Also be sure that you have permissions in the directory where the venv folder is. so like if you `ls -ail .` you should see the non-sudo user has `chown craver2000:craver2000 the_dir`

You may also be able to do something like:

```
sudo cp -R /path/to/dist-packages/pigpio venv_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages
sudo chown -R $USER venv_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

And upon further examination you might be able to just copy the pigpio file to your virtualenv like:

```
deactivate
cp pigpio/pigpio.py venv_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages
source venv_test/bin/activate
```

And digging a bit more here is an untested install, but hey the module imports using a venv :):

```
162  sudo apt-get install build-essential
  163  git clone https://github.com/joan2937/pigpio.git
  164  pip
  165  pip install virtualenv
  166  python -m pip install virtualenv
  167  sudo pip install virtualenv
  168  sudo pip install --upgrade pip
  169  virtualenv
  170  virtualenv venv_test
  171  cd pigpio/
  172  ls
  173  nano Makefile
  174  make
  175  make install
  176  mkdir /opt/pigpio
  177  sudo mkdir /opt/pigpio
  178  chown $USER /opt/pigpio
  179  sudo chown $USER /opt/pigpio
  180  make install
  181  source ../venv_test/bin/activate
  182  ls
  183  make install
  184  sudo mkdir /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages
  187  sudo chown $USER /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages
  211  sudo chmod 4755 /sbin/ldconfig
  213  sudo chmod 4755 /sbin/ldconfig.real
  214  make install
  215  history
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply jmunsch. I done the steps as mentioned and now just made the hacky edit to the pigpio makefile as suggested, so L34 now shows: prefix = $(pwd)/venv_test. I then managed to 'make' the file successfully. However, at the 'make install 'step, I got an error: (venv_test) pi@raspberrypi:~/pigpio $ make install
install -m 0755 -d                /opt/pigpio/cgi
install -m 0755 -d                /venv_test/include
install: cannot create directory ‘/venv_test’: Permission denied
Makefile:80: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 1
.Any ideas why?

Comment: @Craver2000 `prefix = /home/myuser/venv_test` is what i changed it to. i'm not sure how makefiles do shell expansion so `$(pwd)` might work differently, just type out the full path where you want it?

Comment: I have changed L34 to `prefix = /home/pi/venv_test`  but I am still recieving an error as shown below. Could you advise me on this?

Comment: `(venv_test) pi@raspberrypi:~/pigpio $ make install
install -m 0755 -d                /opt/pigpio/cgi
install -m 0755 -d                /home/pi/venv_test/include
install -m 0644 pigpio.h          /home/pi/venv_test/include
install -m 0644 pigpiod_if.h      /home/pi/venv_test/include
install -m 0644 pigpiod_if2.h     /home/pi/venv_test/include
install -m 0755 -d                /home/pi/venv_test/lib
install -m 0755 libpigpio.so      /home/pi/venv_test/lib
........`

Comment: `.......Writing /home/pi/venv_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pigpio-1.38-py2.7.egg-infoif which python3; then python3 setup.py install; fi/usr/bin/python3running installrunning buildrunning build_pycreating build/libcopying pigpio.py -> build/librunning install_libcreating /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packageserror: could not create '/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages': Permission deniedMakefile:80: recipe for target 'install' failedmake: *** [install] Error 1`

Comment: @Craver2000 line 184 of the history that i posted

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! It worked! my script which imports and uses the pigpio library in the virtual env is now working.  For me, the additional steps I needed to do based on your history (after L34 edit) were L184, L187, L211 and then `make install`.

Comment: @Craver2000 nice work thanks for following through with testing it out. That's great that it works from within a virtualenv. just to let you know though setting 4755 for ldconfig might be considered unsafe, but hey who's checking. ;)

Comment: Thanks jmunsch. Since I'm still learning, I was just wondering if you could tell me more about the setting 4755 for ldconfig,i.e. what that does and what situations can I apply it to?

Comment: @Craver2000 it sets the SUID bit, it basically gives users the permission to use the binary. I guess it would be used if user permissions don't matter, and the install instructions are not meant for a virtualenv ;)